# All consumers of a Provider will re-render when value prop changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to understand React Context API better. In the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) I stumbled on this paragraph:

> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
> whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. The propagation from
> Provider to its descendant consumers (including .contextType and
> useContext) is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method, so the
> consumer is updated even when an ancestor component skips an update.

I'm having a hard time understanding this, since the definition of a consumer is a little unclear to me. If I try to create an example [(codingsandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-buck-qfhom?file=/src/App.js) the result is always the same: **If the value changes, all children (not consumers) of the Provider rerender.**

I'd love to understand what is meant by the paragraph above. Is there a case where the context value updates without triggering a new render of its children (preferably in a function component)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, according to your sandbox, is how state is being managed in the main app component.

```
  //your useState
  const [store, setStore] = React.useState([]);
  
  //the button that is setting the state
  <button onClick={() => setStore([])}>Reset store value</button>
```

This causes the **state in the component to change**, which rerenders the App component itself, which causes a rerender of all it's children. If you wish to update the context state only, you should avoid storing the value in state and rather directly [mount the function within the Context Object](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component) for logic to change the property within the value object

Comment: Ok, it certainly looks like it. But in this case I'd argue that the react documentation is wrong here. For me, consumers does not mean "all children".

Comment: @Xen_mar It implies it. After all, when you render a component, it does need to call the render functions for all children (unless they opt out of that with e.g. `shouldComponentUpdate()` or `React.memo`).

Comment: Thanks @AKX - I'd still argue that this is not completely correct. To me, a consumer would be a component that either uses `useContext` or `<context.Consumer>`. To me, the paragraph implies that a value change would only update the consumers and their respective subtrees. This would mean that components would have a subscription relationship to their provider vs. a prop-based relationship.

Comment: hey, I have figured out why this is the case, will edit the answer

Comment: After all, if we look at something like redux, we also see a subscriber-consumer based relationship that only updates respective subtrees.

Comment: Thanks! I actually hadn't looked at it from this perspective. Just a short note to the docs: Nowhere are they "mounting the function directly within the context object". The docs store the value in state, too. They're just defining an initial shape of the context that mirrors the expected shape. I tried putting a mutable `ref.current`value into a context, but without the rerendering nothing is happening. So I guess its all-or-nothing when it comes to rerendering. I'm still quite sure the docs on this are wrong or at least misleading.